# GD lib resize image few turns black

Tags: php, file-upload, gd, image-resizing

I am experiencing an issue with image upload by users, out of 100 say 1 or 2 images uploaded are completely black.

here is the function i use for resizing their images, can someone see what could be wrong here?

```
function resize_image($oldimage_name, $new_image_name){
    list($owidth,$oheight) = getimagesize($oldimage_name);
    $width = 250; $height = 250;    
    $im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    $img_src = imagecreatefromjpeg($oldimage_name);
    imagecopyresampled($im, $img_src, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $owidth, $oheight);
    imagejpeg($im, $new_image_name, 90);
    imagedestroy($im);
    unlink($oldimage_name);
    return true;
}
```

my error handling code

```
        if($_FILES['file']['name'] == ''){
            $error[] = 'Please attach your photo.';
        }elseif($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 2097152){
            $error[] = 'Selected image size is too large, upload under 2mb.';
        }elseif(!in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg"))){
            $error[] = 'We accept only JPG / JPEG image format.';
        }
```

Here is the file upload

```
if($_FILES['file']['name']!='')
            {
                $tmp_name = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
                $namefile = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                $cname = str_replace(' ', '-', $candidate_name);
                $ext = end(explode(".", $namefile));
                $fileUpload = move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"uploads/images/".$image_name);
                $image_name= $cname.'-'.time().".".$ext;                
                resize_image($tmp_name,"uploads/images/".$image_name);
                $img = ''.$image_name.'';
            }
```

what could be causing this? i just cannot seem to understand. out of 100 just 1 or 2 images are completely black i do not know what the users are uploading either because when i try to upload different image types it definitely does not allow me to upload any png or gif files.

Appreciate your time and help